# List<IFormFile> Files always 0 Files count in AspNetCore 3.1 Web Api

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm building a REST API application where I want to give an option to users they can upload single or multiple files, I checked with uploading files from Postman but in my controller, I always get zero files, Please help me to know what wrong I'm doing

[Postman Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES6mD.png)
Below is my code.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> UploadInvoice([FromForm(Name = "Files")] List <IFormFile> uploadFiles) {
   try {
     long size = uploadFiles.Sum(f => f.Length);

     if (uploadFiles == null || uploadFiles.Count <= 0) {
       Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
       return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
         message = "No files found."
       }), "application/json");
     }

     var filesToUpload = new List < FileUploadModel > ();

     foreach(var file in uploadFiles) {
       var fileGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
       var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @ "wwwroot\docs", $ "{fileGuid}{Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)}");

       using(var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) {
         await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
         await fileStream.FlushAsync();
       }
     }
     return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
       message = ""
     }), "application/json");
   } catch (Exception ex) {

     Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
     return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
       message = ex.Message
     }), "application/json");
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hey, what is the key in the form you are submitting via postman. Is it Files with an uppercase F?

Comment: When you have a breakpoint in the first line, check the content of the `this.Request` property. Do you see your file data there somewhere? Please [edit] your question to include a screenshot of the debug/inspect info of the `this.Request` property to show info about the actual request like the form data.

Comment: @menachem, Yes it is Files with F,

Comment: Request.Form.Files have values, I get the files, and using directly from this I'm able to save files, but I want to implement the same functionality using IFormFile.

Comment: Are you actually sending a `multipart/form-data` request?

Comment: Yes, I was sending using multipart/form-data, but I found this was an issue with one of the files I was trying to upload, this can be closed. Thank you